# NextAuth TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, server-side-rendering, next-auth

This appears wnenever I try to sign in, with each privider I have:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error fetch failed {
  error: {
    message: 'fetch failed',
    stack: 'TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
      '    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: 'fetch failed'
}
```

After signing in I do not have a redirection to my home page here '/'. I cannot see that I am logged in. When I visit this link  I see correct information

> http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session

May be there is a problem with getServerSideProps but anyway I cannot understand why it happens and how to solve it

**.env**

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

EMAIL_FROM=noreply@example.com
EMAIL_SERVER=smtp:

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=

DISCORD_CLIENT_ID=
DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET=

AUTH_SECRET=myPassword
```

**[...nextauth].js**

```
    export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "E-mail", type: "text", placeholder: "youremail@mail.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "password" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });

        if (!user) return null;

        return user;

      },
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
}
```

**pages/index.js**

```
import { Inter } from "@next/font/google";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {setUserState} from "@//tools/redux/userSlice";
import { getSession, useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home(props: any) {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (session) dispatch(setUserState(session.user));
    })()
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center flex-col my-32">
        {!props.user &&
          <>
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-gray-500 ">You are not logged in!</h1>
            <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
          </>
        }
        {props.user &&
        <>
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-gray-500   ">Welcome, {props.user?.email ?? 'User'}</h1>
          <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </>
      }
      </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: any) {
  const session = await getSession(ctx);
  if (!session) {
    return {
      props: {}
    };
  }
  const { user } = session;
  return {
    props: { user }
  };
}
```

There is a possibility it happaned after next build.